# RXTX still reading data when device disconnected

Tags: java, rxtx

I use RXTX library in java, if I write space ascii(32) to outpurstream I can get data, unless I can't get. I dont know why and it can be a problem ?

The problem is: I get data from a ohmmeter, I measure the product but when I take off probe, ohmetter display a value and then display "0.L" but I always get last data so I can't detect if ohmetter measure a product or not.

For example

02.00 OHM    (coreect value) >>
125.20 OHM   (while taking off probe) >>
0.L          (after take off the probe)

I always get 125.20 OHM, how can I get the 0.L value ?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
public class SerialComm {

SerialPort serialPort;
OutputStream outStream = null;
InputStream inStream = null;

public SerialComm() {
    super();
}

void connect(String portName) throws Exception {

    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier", 5000);
    int baudRate = 9600;

    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(
            baudRate,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    serialPort.setFlowControlMode(
            SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
    setSerialListener();
}

public void initIOStream() throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        inStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        write();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        try {
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

public void write() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    outStream.write(32);
    outStream.flush();
}

private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[400];

private void readSerial() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
    try {
        initIOStream();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int availableBytes = inStream.available();
        if (availableBytes > 0) {
            inStream.read(readBuffer, 0, availableBytes);
            System.out.println("value:  " + new String(readBuffer, 0, 30));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

private class SerialEventHandler implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        System.out.println("event.getEventType()" + event.getEventType());
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE: {
                try {
                    readSerial();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private class ReadThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                readSerial();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setSerialListener() throws InterruptedException, TooManyListenersException {
    new Thread(new ReadThread()).start();
}

public void setSerialEventHandler(SerialPort serialPort) throws Exception {
    try {
        initIOStream();
        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialEventHandler());
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception {
    SerialComm serial = new SerialComm();
    serial.connect("COM3");
}
```

}

Comment: What exact ohmmeter are you using?

Comment: Prova Model 700 Ohmmetter

Answer (score 0):

RXTX is designed for serial communication, the resistance that you get between serial ports is based on the internal TTL to RS232 converter on your motherboard (or usb to serial converter) and therefore is more of a hardware question.

I am guessing from your question that you are attempting to pull flow control pins up or down, this will effectively produce a voltage on the pins (and has nothing to do with resistance between pins. )

if you post a code example I can assist with any potential bugs in the code. and expected output from the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an issue which is related to the Prova 700, because the behaviour you describe is exactly the behaviour one would expect from an Ohm-meter. Basically by removing the probe from the resistor the resistance rises until it reaches a level which is not measurable by the device (the resistance of air). In this case the internal status of the device will say: We have reached infinitive resistance and will display 0.0L.

I am not 100% sure what your exact goal is with your software but I assume a workflow like this:

- User attaches probes a resistor
- On removal of the probes your software automatically records the data

However, as you can see this will not work out.

Please take a look into the instruction manual for the Prova 700. What exactly does the manual say about the RS-232 protocol? Other devices like this have an instruction protocol which is talked on the serial line such that you are able to send commands into the system. One could then perform a workflow like this

- User attaches probes to resistor
- Presses button on the computer
- Computer sends a command to the Ohm-meter
- Ohm-meter replies with current resistance
- Computer stores resistance and shows a message that it is save to remove the probes

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to get resistance value and compare with product property, if the value in tolerans product pass the test. The problem is if the user make mistake and measure while probe is removed because I get still value and if product wire have problem I must get 0.L value even probes attached.